# In flask wtf forms MultipleCheckboxField, how to set different attributes to each checkbox choice?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

How to set html attributes to each of the checkbox choices (key and value) (different for each choice)?

My code:

```
class MultipleCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = CheckboxInput()

class Form(FlaskForm)
    course = MultipleCheckboxField("Courses",choices=[
            (str(c["_id"]), c["course"], {"data-duration": c["duration"]})
            for c in db.Courses.find({})
        ])
```

Adding `{"data-example": 'example-value'}` works with `SelectMultipleField` but doing the same with my custom `MultipleCheckboxField`, I'm getting an error: `TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data-duration'`

Comment: Your title: wtf forms or wtforms?